# How to add pointers in Java programming language?

Tags: java, c++, pointers

I am trying to convert the C++ programs into Java programs but I am not able to get the syntax of pointers in java programming language. What should I do?

Comment: No pointers in java sorry

Comment: @coder what about a structure containing nothing but a reference to another structure?  That behaves a lot like a pointer, no?

Comment: So, what syntax should I use in Java instead of pointers??

Comment: Your question has your answer... Behaves like a pointer, not a pointer... Also as for OP there is no syntax for pointers in java....

Comment: You can't add pointers in C++ either.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague because you haven't specified what you need the pointers for. If you need pointer arithmetic, the closest thing in Java is the `Unsafe` API, which is proprietary and not part of the official JDK API.

If you need to just pass pointers around and dereference them, no syntax for that is needed in Java—actually you must *remove* the syntax from C++ code to get the equivalent in Java:

- `ptr->method()` converts to `ptr.method()`
- `*ptr` becomes just `ptr`
- `&obj` becomes just `obj`.

This is because Java exclusively uses pointers to refer to objects, so the syntax simply *assumes* them.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, there's no pointers (actually, everything, except primitives, is a pointer, but you want to change passed variable, ain't you?) in Java, so you should think of how you can implement the same functionality without pointers.

If you can't succeed in this, you can make your methods accept something, which holds reference for another variable, for example, `AtomicReference<T>` (`AtomicInteger`/`AtomicLong` for, correspondingly, `int` and `long`).

It would be something like:

```
void changeMyString(AtomicReference<String> ref) {
    ref.set("Hello, World!");
}
```